# regular expression replace all except captured expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to find everything except for the data I don't want to replace. I'm then wanting to replace everything except for the found expression.

My match is to find all words that start with "CN=" and ends with 12 characters after. I'm currently using the logic (!?CN=)\w{12}. It finds the two occurrences in the string. However, I'm wanting to find everything but these two occurrences and find everything else and replace everything else with an empty value so that I just have the two CN= word values.

The attached image shows my testing and results. I'm wanting the reverse affect.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFEdJ.png)

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your question to show us sample data, what you are trying to match, and sample output.

Comment: Just concatenate all the matches.

Comment: Note that you can get a link to that regex test with the share button. That is much more useful than an image.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.*` to capture whatever comes before a match, and add `$` (end-of-input) as alternative for `CN=\w{12}`:

```
.*?($|CN=\w{12})
```

Replace with just the captured groups:

```
$1
```

Demo on [Java regex tester](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/89f1afa8-cce9-4ada-b792-767fdf5fbcac)

NB: I did not add the `!?` as you wrote *...words that start with "CN="*. If you really need to keep the exclamation mark before `CN=`, then you should add it to the regular expression.

Comment: Did this answer suit your needs? Could you accept it or leave a comment?